# Android: Possibility to implement "sharing screenshot" directly through online chat feature

Tags: android

i have just started to develop a basic app, and have integrated an SDK for online chat, using which customers could chat with customer support.
I want implement if someone want to share screen shot, it should be done without going into gallelry just like android native shows default apps for sharing like whatsapp,facebook, my app also could be reflected there.
Is it possible??